# How to select top X from a Row_number in SQL Server ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a data sample,  and now i want to get data using `TOP X` combine `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
IndexNo ProductName
1       Black
2       Blue
3       Brown
4       Green
5       Red
6       White
7       Yellow
```

As follow in this case, i want to get the data, which after run SQL Statement, result as

```
IndexNo ProductName
3       Brown
4       Green
5       Red
```

I use this sql statement for this case, but i get this error `Invalid column name 'IndexNo'` , this is sql statement .

```
SELECT TOP 3  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TEMPA.ProductName) AS IndexNo, TEMPA.ProductName  
FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT ProductName FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ProductType ='Food'
) AS TEMPA
WHERE IndexNo  between 3 and 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use another level of subquery with parentheses.

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TEMPA.ProductName) AS IndexNo, TEMPA.ProductName  
FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT ProductName FROM PRODUCTS 
) AS TEMPA
  ) as TEMPB
WHERE IndexNo  between 3 and 5
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e5682/4)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `ROW_NUMBER` into Common Table Expression and apply `between` on the outer level:

```
with cte as (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TEMPA.ProductName) AS IndexNo, TEMPA.ProductName  
FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT ProductName FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ProductType ='Food'
) AS TEMPA
) select top 3 * from cte 
WHERE cte.IndexNo  between 3 and 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `ROW_NUMBER()` in one scope and filter it in another scope...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) AS ix FROM example
)
  indexed_example
WHERE
  ix BETWEEN 3 AND 5
```

This is the ***NOT*** same for `TOP` and `ORDER BY`, as these are applied ***after*** the `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, so this would work fine...

```
SELECT TOP(3)
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC)  ix
FROM
  example
ORDER BY
  ix
```

This is especially useful to your case when using `ORDER BY ? OFFSET ? FETCH ?` instead of `TOP`.

```
SELECT
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC)  ix
FROM
  example
ORDER BY
  ix DESC
  OFFSET 2 ROWS            -- Skip 2 rows
  FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY   -- Fetch the 3rd, 4th and 5th rows.
```

In your example, you're also using `DISTINCT` which is applied ***after*** the `SELECT` values are calculated, but you *could* use `GROUP BY` instead as it is applied ***before*** the `SELECT` values are calculated.

```
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Products.ProductName)  ix,
  Products.ProductName
FROM
  Products
WHERE
  Products.ProductType = 'Food'
GROUP BY
  Products.ProductName
ORDER BY
  ix DESC
  OFFSET 2 ROWS
  FETCH NEXT 3 ROWS ONLY
```

1. All the joins in the `FROM` clause first *(nothing to do in your case)*
2. Apply the `WHERE` clause
3. Apply the `GROUP BY` clause *(same effect as your DISTINCT)*
4. Calculate the `SELECT` values, including the `ROW_NUMBER()`
5. Apply the `ORDER BY` including the `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT` clauses

Everything you wanted, without needing to next anything in sub-queries.